# GeoPandas spatial join - no matching rows in the resultant dataset

Tags: pandas, geospatial, geopandas

I have two GeoPandas DataFrames that I am attempting to join. I set the `crs` for both and then use `sjoin` and `sjoin_nearest`, however, I am not seeing any results. The columns are `NaNs`.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'id': [0, 1, 2], 
                    'Lat': [41.8896878, 41.8854416, 33.155480],
                    'Long': [-87.6188015, -87.615478, -96.731630]
                  })


gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df1.Long, df1.Lat))

# set crs for buffer calculations
gdf1.set_crs("ESRI:102003", inplace=True)



df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'val': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                    'Lat': [41.88545, 41.885507, 33.15549],
                    'Long': [-87.61762, -87.615377, -96.73164]
                  })

 
    

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2.Long, df2.Lat))

# set crs for buffer calculations
gdf2.set_crs("ESRI:102003", inplace=True)


# Spatial Join
joined_gdf = gpd.sjoin_nearest(
                               gdf1,  # Point geometry
                               gdf2,  # Point geometry
                               how='left',
                               max_distance = 0.001, # in meters
                               distance_col = "distances"
                              )
```

Second approach tried using `sjoin`,

```
gdf1 = gdf1.set_crs(4326, allow_override=True) 
gdf2 = gdf2.set_crs(4326, allow_override=True) 


joined_gdf = gpd.sjoin(
                        gdf1,
                        gdf2,
                        predicate = 'intersects',
                        how = 'left'
                      )
```

I do not see the results that I'd expect i.e no matches / rows in the resultant joined dataframe. Not sure what is going on with the spatial joins.

The columns from right table are all `NaNs`. The `crs` for both DataFrames is:

```
<Derived Projected CRS: ESRI:102003>
Name: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: United States (USA) - CONUS onshore - Alabama; Arizona; Arkansas; California; Colorado; Connecticut; Delaware; Florida; Georgia; Idaho; Illinois; Indiana; Iowa; Kansas; Kentucky; Louisiana; Maine; Maryland; Massachusetts; Michigan; Minnesota; Mississippi; Missouri; Montana; Nebraska; Nevada; New Hampshire; New Jersey; New Mexico; New York; North Carolina; North Dakota; Ohio; Oklahoma; Oregon; Pennsylvania; Rhode Island; South Carolina; South Dakota; Tennessee; Texas; Utah; Vermont; Virginia; Washington; West Virginia; Wisconsin; Wyoming.
- bounds: (-124.79, 24.41, -66.91, 49.38)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic
- method: Albers Equal Area
Datum: North American Datum 1983
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your join:

- You have used `set_crs` instead of `to_crs` to transform your geometries. `set_crs` simply declares the CRS of the geometries; `to_crs` actually transforms them from the declared CRS to another.
- Additionally, your `max_distance` argument to `sjoin` is too small, so there is no valid match within 0.01 meters, and there are no results returned. Increase the `max_distance` parameter, e.g. to 1000, or omit it from the arguments to get a match for all points.

## `set_crs` vs `to_crs`

The crs for your points is lat/lon (e.g. WGS84/EPSG:4326). You should *set* the crs as this using [`gdf.set_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs), then convert to the desired crs using [`gdf.to_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html), which actually transforms the data:

```py
gdf1 = (
    gdf1
    .set_crs("EPSG:4326")   # set_crs: declare that the lat/lons are in WGS84
    .to_crs("ESRI:102003")  # to_crs:  transform the geometries to ESRI:102003
)
```

From the [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs) API docs:

> [**`GeoDataFrame.set_crs`**](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs) *`(crs=None, epsg=None, inplace=False, allow_override=False)`*
>
> Set the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) of the [`GeoDataFrame`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame).
>
> NOTE: The underlying geometries are not transformed to this CRS. To transform the geometries to a new CRS, use the [`to_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) method.

Compare with the docstring for [`geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs):

> [**`GeoDataFrame.to_crs`**](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs) *`(crs=None, epsg=None, inplace=False)`*
>
> Transform geometries to a new coordinate reference system.
>
> Transform all geometries in an active geometry column to a different coordinate reference system. The `crs` attribute on the current GeoSeries must be set. Either `crs` or `epsg` may be specified for output.

When interpreted using your code, the values you provided are not within the domain of valid points for the crs you’re using (since they’re all within a hundred meters from (0, 0) lat/lon). If you change your code to correctly *set* the CRS as WGS84/EPSG:4326 and then transform the CRS with *to_crs*, they will correctly be points in the continental United States.

## `max_distance` is too small

After updating to the above, note that your `max_distance` parameter is too stringent to allow any of the points to match. If you relax this max_distance parameter to `1000` or don't provide it, all three points will find a match.

Note that providing a max_distance is a good idea for catching issues - you would not have found this problem so quickly if you had allowed matches at any distance! But you do need to keep in mind that a too-strict max_distance will result in a lack of matches.

## complete soluttion

My full working runthrough of your code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'id': [0, 1, 2],
                    'Lat': [41.8896878, 41.8854416, 33.155480],
                    'Long': [-87.6188015, -87.615478, -96.731630]
                  })

gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df1, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df1.Long, df1.Lat))

# set crs for buffer calculations
gdf1 = gdf1.set_crs("epsg:4326").to_crs("ESRI:102003")

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'val': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                    'Lat': [41.88545, 41.885507, 33.15549],
                    'Long': [-87.61762, -87.615377, -96.73164]
                  })

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df2.Long, df2.Lat))

# set crs for buffer calculations
gdf2 = gdf2.set_crs("epsg:4326").to_crs("ESRI:102003")

# Spatial Join
joined_gdf = gpd.sjoin_nearest(
    gdf1,  # Point geometry
    gdf2,  # Point geometry
    how='left',
    max_distance = 1000, # in meters
    distance_col = "distances",
)
```

this yields the following:

```py
In [2]: joined_gdf
Out[2]:
   id   Lat_left  Long_left                        geometry  index_right val  Lat_right  Long_right   distances
0   0  41.889688 -87.618802   POINT (689683.192 522217.641)            0   a  41.885450  -87.617620  484.004306
1   1  41.885442 -87.615478   POINT (689997.829 521768.561)            1   b  41.885507  -87.615377   11.081472
2   2  33.155480 -96.731630  POINT (-67811.160 -485877.116)            2   c  33.155490  -96.731640    1.450918
```

Comment: In your question all the points are the same, so this doesn’t match. Please update your question to clarify the issue rather than trying to put code or data in a comment.

Comment: i have updated the question with sample `coordinates` from 2 datasets that I'd expect to match.

Comment: any ideas on what might be going on? I tried to do a spatial join with `crs` as `4326` but it didn't work either.

Comment: so in your updated problem, you still use `set_crs` instead of `to_crs`. if you correctly use `set_crs("epsg:4326").to_crs("ESRI:102003")`, then you can see that the shapes are close, but more than 0.01m apart. if you relax the `max_distance` tolerance to `1000` (1 km) then they all match. The first two points are 484m apart, the second two 11m, and the third 1.5m (in the `"ESRI:102003"` projection). So none of them match to the tolerance you have.

Comment: The distance between the points seems quite high. could this be because the coordinates in the two dataframes are of different precision? For example, `41.8896878` and `41.88545` are `lats` for the same location. Can we expect to obtain more matches if we increased the precision level? They were both geocoded differently `df1` is using `mapbox` api, `df2` is something else.

Comment: Yes. You can look them up on google maps if you want. The precision matters a lot when a degree is roughly 100km. This isn’t a geopandas issue though.

Comment: Those lats are not just a precision difference either. They are actually just 0.004 degrees (roughly 400m in North America) apart. Could it be that one of your sources is using wgs84 and the other NAD83 or some other horizontal datum?

Comment: it could be. how do I check? We are applying the same transformations to both dataframes tho.

Comment: It would likely be in the documentation of the geocoding services you’re using. There is no way to check just from the data. If they’re using different horizontal datums then you should set a different crs for the two source datasets prior to transforming them.

Comment: `df1` is geocoded using mapbox geocoding api, `df2` is an external data source and am not sure about the horizontal datums. I am thinking we'll just geocode `df2` using mapbox, and then attempt to join, so that they are consistent. would that work?

Comment: Sorry - I can’t design your whole project for you. I have no idea what you’re doing and am not a mapbox consultant. The answer to your geopandas question is the one I posted. I’d make sure to align your datums, and that’s as far as I can go. Feel free to ask a different question with different goals if you need more help. Good luck!

Comment: `gdf.crs` does show the `Datum`. Both DataFrames are `Datum: North American Datum 1983
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich`

Comment: Huh. Since they’re NAD83 you’ll want to use a different crs or skip the set_crs step since it seems they’re already set. But that doesn’t solve your problem. Presumably one (or both) of your sources isn’t all that accurate or isn’t finding a match to your search criteria. C’est la vie.

Comment: To be clear, I only the output of `gdf.crs` when I have run the `set_crs` and `to_crs` as you had suggested. I don't see any output before running that line.

Comment: Oh. Yeah well then that doesn’t tell you anything. Many shapefiles include the crs so if it had it when you read it in from the source that would tell you something.